# Splitting lemma, a detail

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let R be a commutative unitary ring and let $0\overset{}{\to}N \overset{f}{\to} M \overset{g}{\to} P \to 0$ a short exact sequence of R-modules. Now suppose that the sequence splits.
**If N and P are submodules of M, then N and P are in direct INNER sum, i.e. $M=N+P$ and $N\cap P=\{0\}$**: this sentence in bold is true (I think), how I can prove it in a rigorous Way?

Comment: You are not understanding what it means to split. Not any isomorphism is valid. There are exact sequences $0 \to M \to M \oplus N \to N \to 0$ which are not split

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. Now I edited the question

Comment: That's not true. For $R = \Bbb Z$, take $M = \Bbb Z$, $N=\{0\}$, $P = 2\Bbb Z$ and let $g$ be multiplication by $2$.

Comment: Ok, so why someone uses the symbol $\oplus$ to indicate both direct extern sum and INNER direct sum. It would be more clear using two different symbol, would'n It? A question: the thesis would be true of I assume that M=N+P? In other words, in the hypothesis of my question, If I also suppose that M=N+P, then can I conclude that $N\cap P=\{0\}$?